# How do I reference the link that was clicked when using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some bootstrap tabs and anchors are the tab. I have the info in an `<ul>` but when I try to grab the anchor that was clicked, I get an undefined. Here's my code.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="steps_view">
  <li class="active"><a href="#" data-selection="step_all">All</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-selection="step_completed">Completed</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-selection="step_na">N/A</a></li>
</ul>


  $(document).on('click','#steps_view',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
```

Shouldn't $(this) point back to the link that was clicked? I also tried $(e) but no go:

```
    var selection = $(this).attr('data-selection');

    console.log(selection);

    $('#steps_view li').removeClass('active');

    $('#'+selection).parent('li').addClass('active');
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your event handler, `$(this)` refers to the element you assigned it to -- `#steps_view`, which isn't an anchor but the `<ul>` containing it. Make your selector more specific:

```
$(document).on('click','#steps_view > li > a',function(e){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [e.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

In a [delegated event](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) handler (which you're using), `this` refers to the element that matches the selector passed to `.on()`, which in your case is `#steps_view`.  When you click on one of the anchors, the `click` event bubbles up the DOM tree: First the event triggers on the anchor element, then on the anchor's parent element, and so on, all the way up to the root `document`.

When the event reaches the `document` - which is where you bound the event handler via `$(document).on(...)` - jQuery looks at the target element (`e.target`) and compares it against the selector you passed to `.on()`.  The selector doesn't match, so it tries the target element's parent (the `li`).  When that fails, it moves to `li`'s parent, `ul#steps_view`.  Since this matches the selector, jQuery calls your event handler function and assigns the `ul#steps_view` element to `this`.  `e.target` exists precisely for that reason: So you can determine which element originally caused the event to fire.

See the [jQuery Event Object reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) for more information.

**Quick tip**: If you set a breakpoint in the "Sources" tab of the Chrome Developer Tools, you can inspect the event object's properties to find what you're looking for.

Comment: Not sure how to use a breakpoint to find out the issue, would you be so kind as to walk me through it?

Comment: Take a look at [Debugging JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging). You set a breakpoint by clicking on the line number you want the debugger to stop on, and then you click one of the anchor elements in the browser. The debugger will pause on that line, at which point you can inspect the `e` variable on the right side of the dev tools.

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely take a look at that!